# Recently installed MikTeX and TeXmaker and am getting an error when I try to build

Tags: miktex, texmaker

When I try to build a file I get the following error:

```
Could not start the command.
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

Do I need to some how link MikTex to my editor?

Comment: Try to start pdflatex from a command line to check if miktex is correctly installed.

Comment: It appears to be working. C:\Users\John>pdflatex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7250 64-bit)
**